# xctool: Tried to install the test host app but failed

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xctool

Trying to get app/logic tests to run through the command line. Right now I am testing out xctool.
It works great on my dev machine, but for some reason starts failing on the Mac mini we are using as a build server.

As it turns out, it **works** if I run it through **VNC** in the terminal.

Update: It now works if ssh'ed.

Now fails only with Jenkins.

```
./xctool.sh -project ~/Downloads/proj/Project.xcodeproj/ -scheme Project -sdk iphonesimulator7.1 clean test
```

And seeing this output:

> ```
>  [Info] Collecting info for testables... (3822 ms)
>   run-test Tests.octest (iphonesimulator7.1, application-test)
>     [Warning] Tried to install the test host app 'xxx' but failed. (31 ms)
>     [Info] Preparing test environment failed; will retry 2 more times (0 ms)
>     [Info] Stopped any existing iOS simulator jobs to get a fresh simulator. (3 ms)
>     [Info] Reset iOS simulator content and settings. (0 ms)
>     [Warning] Tried to install the test host app 'xxx' but failed. (27 ms)
>     [Info] Preparing test environment failed; will retry 1 more time (0 ms)
>     [Info] Stopped any existing iOS simulator jobs to get a fresh simulator. (2 ms)
>     [Info] Reset iOS simulator content and settings. (0 ms)
>     [Warning] Tried to install the test host app 'xxx' but failed. (24 ms)
>     [Warning] Preparing test environment failed. (0 ms)
> ```

Tests fail with:

> ```
> Test did not run: Failed to install the test host app 'xxx': Failed for unknown reason.
> ```

Whereas on my dev machine, I see the iOS simulator pop up, on the mac mini I don't see anything.

What is the issue here?

If I try to run on 7.0:

```
./xctool.sh -project ~/Downloads/proj/Project.xcodeproj/ -scheme Project -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 clean test
```

I see:

> ```
> Check dependencies
> No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386 x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=armv6).
> ```

On 6.1, I receive a bunch of compiler errors.

Looking at the mini's system.log I am seeing some unusual messages that yield little on search:

> launchd_sim_trampoline[69113]: Bogus bootstrap.plist specified.
>
> com.apple.launchd.peruser.260[80978] (com.apple.iphonesimulator.launchd.5772e154[69113]): Exited with code: 78
>
> com.apple.launchd.peruser.260[80978] (com.apple.iphonesimulator.launchd.5772e154): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds

We are observing similar results as listed here: [xctool issue](https://github.com/facebook/xctool/issues/45)

Unfortunately, one of the solutions listed we have already tried, that of adding a SessionCreate key pair value to org.jenkins-ci.plist, and moving that plist to our user's ~/Library/LaunchAgents folder.

This link also is similar to what we are encountering: [xctool issue 2](https://github.com/facebook/xctool/issues/162)
Unfortunately we aren't using tmux, so the solution does not apply.

Comment: Any updates at all here?  Experiencing the same issue on my end.

Comment: What version of XCode are you using?